# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple values for same key 'request'

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Anyone know what this error means? It's coming from the Google Cloud Endpoints processor and the error message gives no detail as to where it's occurring. Here is the full stack trace I see in the error log:

```
com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple values for same key 'request'
```

**UPDATE:**

Through trial and error I found the offending method signature:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "createMasterDefaultCampaignsAndScriptsAndSchedules", path = "createMasterDefaultCampaignsAndScriptsAndSchedules", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public ArrayList<Campaign> createMasterDefaultCampaignsAndScriptsAndSchedules(Calendar pCalendar, Company pCompany) {
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: As a workaround I ended up having to pass the id of the JDO object and then pull it back out of the datastore, which is pretty in efficient.

I regard this as a bug and have filed an issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10218&thanks=10218&ts=1383276126

Answer (score 2):

Only one entity type parameter is allowed with endpoints. You must enclose all parameters in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense, I have an api method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProgress", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void saveProgress(Progress progress, Token token){
}
```

They force me to combine this two unrelated object,`progress` and `token` into one single class, which make it looks very unreadable.

Comment: Yes, it sucks, but that's the downside of the strong typed world. In Javascript is super trivial to add or remove properties from an object.